# How to best configure gedit to work with Django?

Tags: django, gedit-plugin

Am looking for a good and free IDE to work with Django framework. I came to learn that gedit is a powerful one with right plugins.

How to best configure gedit to work with Django ?

My requirements include -

- easy navigation (finding usages, declarations etc)
- auto completion
- replacements/updates across files
- (obviously) editing/debugging python, CSS/HTML, database queries etc
- (optionally) integration with GitHub

Am new to Python/Django, so please suggest any other plugins that might be useful.

Answer (score 0):

you can use [Sublime Text](http://www.sublimetext.com/)  wirh Djaneiro for django and python, [SublimeCodeIntel](http://sublimecodeintel.github.io/SublimeCodeIntel)